# Eliminating oxalates in beetroot without losing any other nutrients by boiling milk and filtering out "crystals"?

Tags: nutrition, cooking

So evidently beets are pretty high in oxalates (152 mg in 136 grams of beets). One of the ways that's proposed for reducing the oxalates in beets is by boiling in water and throwing the water away, which can reduce the amount of oxalates by up to 90%:

https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/15826055/

This essentially means that 90% of the oxalates are leached into the water. However this also means most of the nutrients are also lost with the oxalates.

To recover those leached nutrients, i was wondering if it would be possible to boil the beets in milk instead?

Since milk contains 125 mg of calcium per 100 ml, using hardly 60 ml of milk (70+ mg of calcium) suffices for 136g of beets (ie, 152 mg of oxalates, as calculated using the formula for calcium oxalate- CaC2O4 -and the atomic weights of the calcium, oxygen and carbon).

Now considering that calcium oxalate is said to be effectively insoluble in water, this should, in theory, mean that we should see its crystals formed in the milk and thus we should be able to filter out those crystals, getting rid of the oxalates and eat the beets with the filtered milk.

However, would this work in practice? Specifically, would the crystals be large enough to be filtered out by commonly available sieves?

Comment: Interesting question.  Seems like the easiest way to answer it would be to try it.  Could you try it yourself?  Also, boiled milk is sometimes said to taste pretty awful.